Capture HAR files on a server
I'm looking for a tool that will allow me to capture HAR files made by a server.
The context is I want HAR files to configure MSW using HAR files and @mswjs/source](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@mswjs/source).
For a straight forward SPA I could just generate a HAR file in the the browser.
But this is a NextJS application, the server will be making HTTP calls as well, and those might not be visible to the browser.
What I'm looking for is something I can wrap or substitute fetch with, or a proxying like service that will record all traffic passed through it.

Possibly something like mitmproxy and har file support is going to do the trick
